# Max of Max on MYSQL

Tags: mysql, max, directed-acyclic-graphs

I'm making an Acyclic Graph database.

TABLE Material (id_item,id_collection,...)
PRIMARY KEY(id_item,id_collection)

(item can be collection itself, item can be collection of collection)

My constraint is id_collection > id_item (to prevent some cycle - 1st step)

So before inserting i need to know  "Max(Max(id_item), Max(id_collection))"

I can get the 2 values them by doing. But can't get max of this :

```
SELECT max(id_collection)
FROM material

UNION

SELECT max(id_item)
FROM Material
```

I tried to do that aswell :

```
    DELIMITER $$ 

CREATE PROCEDURE `findmax` 
   (  
   ) 
   BEGIN 

     DECLARE max_item SMALLINT;
     DECLARE max_collection SMALLINT;
     DECLARE max_of_both SMALLINT;

     SELECT MAX(id_item)
     INTO max_item
     FROM material

     SELECT MAX(id_collection)
     INTO max_collection
     FROM material

     SET max_of_both = MAX(max_item, max_collection)
   END$$ 

DELIMITER ;
```

I'm running out of Gas. Anyone got an idea plz?

Best regards,

Falt

N.B. 2 useful sources about acyclic graph :

- [Database Soup : Trigger prevent cycles in PostgreSQL](http://www.databasesoup.com/2015/02/tree-join-tables-preventing-cycles.html)
- [CodeProject : Acyclic Graph Modelisation](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/22824/A-Model-to-Represent-Directed-Acyclic-Graphs-DAG-o)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to use the [`GREATEST()`](http://www.w3resource.com/mysql/comparision-functions-and-operators/greatest-function.php) function in MySQL.

Try this:

```
SELECT GREATEST(
   (SELECT MAX(id_item) FROM material),
   (SELECT MAX(id_collection) FROM material));
```

This will select the largest item, whether that's the MAX(id_item) or MAX(id_collection).

**EDIT**

Something that may look a little cleaner. The `GREATEST()` function takes the largest of the parameters that it is passed, so if you used it by itself it would return however many rows are in the table, but selecting the id_item or id_collection, which ever is larger. That being said, you can wrap `GREATEST` inside of `MAX()` to achieve the same task:

```
SELECT MAX(GREATEST(id_item, id_collection))
FROM material;
```

Here is an [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/613cb/3) example with both.

Comment: Awesome! i did a couple of try with greatest but in wrong way (i used greatest(max(id_item), max(id_collection) from material. Forgot to mention it.

Thx a lot for helping me.

Comment: @Falt4rm no problem. If this is the solution you use, feel free to accept it by clicking the checkmark next to the answer so future readers know what solved your problem.

Comment: Yeah, sure was searching the button. Found it!